# sudo: psql: command not found: can't fix it

Tags: postgresql

When I run

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I get the

```
sudo: psql: command not found
```

error. I can't get it to work.

```
# locate psql
/etc/alternatives/psql.1.gz
/usr/bin/psql
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/psql.1.gz
/var/lib/postgresql/.psql_history
```

and

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/psql': File exists
```

Didn't work. Postgresql is running and doing fine, though.

Comment: What does `sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/psql` return? Is the environment for user **postgres** defined?

Comment: @ajgringo619 It returns `sudo: /usr/bin/psql: command not found`

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176997/sudo-as-another-user-with-their-environment

Comment: "command not found" can sometimes happen if the program has the wrong binary architecture for your system - check with `file /usr/bin/psql` and `uname -m`

Comment: @steekdriver the first one gives `/# file /usr/bin/psql
/etc/magic, 4: Warning: using regular magic file `/usr/share/misc/magic'
/usr/bin/psql: broken symbolic link to ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
`, the second one ` uname -m
x86_64`

Comment: @parsecer apologies - the command should probably have been `file -L` (to resolve symlinks) but even then, if it resolves to a wrapper script the result is not likely to be helpful

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, `/usr/bin/psql` is a symbolic link to a Perl script that figures out how to locate the default PostgreSQL instance to connect to, and then launches the real psql binary corresponding to that instance with the necessary connection parameters.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/perl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 nov.  14 13:23 /usr/bin/psql -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

See the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html) of `pg_wrapper` for more details.

Based on the comments, the target of the link is broken somehow. Reinstalling the `postgresql-client-common` package might help.